# How do I show that $\sum_{1\leq b<n}\{\frac{ab}{n}\}=\frac{n-1}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ be coprime to $n$.

How do I show that $\sum_{1\leq b<n}\{\frac{ab}{n}\}=\frac{n-1}{2}$

where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

I'm not sure how to start this, any help would be great!

Comment: (1) Can you show it when $a=1$?  (2) Can you show that $(\{ab/n\} : 1 \leq b < n)$ is a permutation of $(\{b/n\} : 1 \leq b < n)$?

Comment: *Hint*: $\{x\}+\{(\text{any integer})-x\}=1$ for all noninteger $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a$ is coprime to $n$, the equation $ab=c\pmod{n}$ can be inverted to $b=a^{-1}c\pmod{n}$ for any $c=0, \ldots,n-1$. So there is a 1-1 correspondence between $b$ and $c$; also $b=0$ corresponds to $c=0$.

Thus $$\sum_{1\le b<n}\{\frac{ ab}{n}\}=\sum_{1\le c<n}\{\frac{c}{n}\}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\le c<n}c=\frac{1}{n}\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$$